# colorbox-rails doesn't work work until I refresh the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I installed colorbox-rails gem for a Rails 4 project. Everything seems to work but only after I refresh the page.

**Installation**

- included gem in Gemfile
- *= require colorbox-rails (css)
- //= require colorbox-rails (.js)

**Code**

<%= link_to image_tag(photo.image.url, class: 'img-thumbnail'), photo.image.remote_url, rel: 'gallery', :data => { :colorbox_static => true, colorbox_photo: true}, target: '_blank' %>

Answer (score 1):

"Only works on refresh" is a common issue for people using Turbolinks, because it changes which Javascript events get fired on a page change. There's a few things to try, assuming this is the issue:

- Use the [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem.
- Disable turbolinks for that specific link by adding `no_turbolink: true` to the `data` hash.
- Disable turbolinks for your application altogether.

More information on turbolinks [here](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) if you need it.